# C# Winform automatically changes its size once an instance of a Matlab dll is created

Tags: c#, matlab, dll, resolution

I am experiencing a very strange behavior in C# Winform. I have made a Matlab dll (2015b 64bit) and added the dll into thereferences of the C# project. As soon as, I create an instance of the class of the dll, the size of the winform significantly decreases. Here is a snapshot of the winform before and after clicking on the button:

Before:
[image: BEFORE]

After:
[image: AFTER]

Here is the ONLY line of code that I am using in this C# project in Button press event:

```
MatlabClass _MatlabClass = new MatlabClass();
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015 in Windows 10 64 bit in a Lenovo Thinkpad laptop.

Does anyone have an idea on what might be the issue.

Comment: I found a solution that works for me here: http://superuser.com/a/812478/383501

Answer (score 2):

Please do not consider this as an answer, I can not comment so I had to write it here. If you look at `InitializeComponent()` and dig deep, you will find that

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();// This function
    }
```

Look for the definition of `InitializeComponent()`

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.Text = "Form1";
    }
```

If you see `AutoScaleMode` you'll find a comment: "Controls, scale relative to the dimensions of the font the classes are using, which is typically the system font".

```
public enum AutoScaleMode
{
    // Summary:
    //     Automatic scaling is disabled.
    None = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Controls scale relative to the dimensions of the font the classes are using,
    //     which is typically the system font.
    Font = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Controls scale relative to the display resolution. Common resolutions are
    //     96 and 120 DPI.
    Dpi = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Controls scale according to the classes' parent's scaling mode. If there
    //     is no parent, automatic scaling is disabled.
    Inherit = 3,
}
```

So if you are using `MatlabClass()` and it uses different default font. You will get a different Window Size. Because Scaling is done based on Default Font Size of the Class. It makes sense as Matlab.dll is published by Mathworks and all other Classes you use are derivative of .Net Framework published by MS. 
This is where everything is going wrong.

Comment: This is very useful and informative comment. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, I commented on my original question. Thanks!